# Asking for a promotion to position higher than expected

Tags: promotion

My company has a tier structure of junior job title, associate job title, job title, senior job title.

I was hired as a junior eight months ago and since the first one I've been working basically independently, basically taking on the tasks of an associate. My work has been well reviewed and I've received a lot of good feedback. I occasionally even help the person who was supposed to support me and other people from my team/new(er) starters.

Currently our budget for raises is frozen so I cannot be promoted. When it's unfrozen I will have been in the company for almost a year and the guidelines suggest 9-12 months for a promotion. Is it extremely unreasonable to ask to skip the associate level? If it is when would it be a good time to ask for a second promotion?

Comment: Promotion typically depends on the skill level, not on the time of stay. Does your company have clear list of expected skills and experiences for each position? Do you possess the skills required for that (level+2) position?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Workplace ! "Is it extremely unreasonable to ask to skip the associate level?": I think this depends a lot of your company, not every company has the same politic on raises, promotions, skipping a level...

Answer (score 3):

> Currently our budget for raises is frozen so I cannot be promoted.
>   When it's unfrozen I will have been in the company for almost a year
>   and the guidelines suggest 9-12 months for a promotion. Is it
>   extremely unreasonable to ask to skip the associate level?

It's not extremely unreasonable. It's not extremely likely, either.

In my experience, it's rather unusual to promote someone two well-defined levels at the same time. As far as I can tell, I've never personally seen it happen any time in my career.

> If it is when would it be a good time to ask for a second promotion?

Apparently, your guidelines suggest 9-12 months. Again, in my experience two promotions every 9-12 months would be rather unusual. But perhaps you are so good at what you do, and so valuable to the company, that they would be willing to do it for you.

All you can do is ask for what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As I don't know where you are from, this answer is based on my location and culture.

I do not think it is unreasonable to ask. If you feel like you can live up to the expectations of that title and you can prove that to the person going over the promotions it is perfectly reasonable to ask.

You should however not be too pushy and just accept their decision, even if it means you do not get the promotion. Because as reasonable it is for you to ask, it's also reasonable for them to want to stick to the system that has been working for them.

Just for a quick example of how you could mention it.

> Hello Boss/manager/HR,
>
> I know we are talking about the promotion to associate, but I would like to ask if we can skip that one and promote me to medior.
>
> I feel like I qualify for this because --Insert Arguments--.
>
> Thanks for the concideration.

Answer (score 0):

> when would it be a good time to ask for a second promotion?

Normally, the company decides *when* promotions a re one, and they are usually done yearly. However, the companies can promote employees at any time, if there are good reasons.

However, consecutive promotions do not come very close to each other, since the person needs to prove that there are abilities / skills to support a promotion.

> Is it extremely unreasonable to ask to skip the associate level?

Not at all unreasonable, if you consider (and gave proof) that you can actually do the job of 2 levels up. however, this might be not agreed by the company, so be ready to be declined the request.